# Change route with vue- <router-link>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a `<router-link to = "/ endreco / test">`, but I need to perform the same behavior on a vue-material tab, something like this: `<md-tab md- icon = "books">` .. to change my route, same as the `href = ""`

What should I do?

I'm using vue.js, the vue-router to control routes and style with vue-material

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my code I have implemented a method which traverses to router to see routes of mentioned name of component, you can easily get idea!

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="mdl-grid">
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col-tablet mdl-cell--hide-phone"></div>
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-phone">
        <div class="image-card" v-for="picture in this.pictures" @click="displaydetails(picture.id) ">
          <div class="image-card__picture">
            <img :src="picture.url" />
          </div>
          <div class="image-card__comment mdl-card__actions">
            <span>{{ picture.comment }}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <router-link class="add-picture-button mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored" to="/postview">
      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import data from '../data'
export default {
 data() {
     return{
         'pictures' : data.pictures 
     }
 },
 methods :{
     displaydetails (id){
         this.$router.push({name:'detailview', params:{id:id}});
         console.log("helo");
     }
 }
}
</script>
```

Hope get something resourceful out of it!

Answer (score 7):

You can add a `@click.native` handler to push to a route manually (the [`.native` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) is needed since the [`md-tab` component](https://vuematerial.io/components/tabs) does not have a `click` event):

```
<md-tab @click.native="$router.push('/endreco/test')">
```

[Here's the documentation on Programmatic Navigation with Vue Router.](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html)

Comment: I entered in this way <md-tab @click = "$ router.push ('/ endreco / test')">, unfortunately it did not work.


I ran the test on a button and it worked perfectly:
  <button @ click = "$ router.push ('/ endreco / test')"> test </ button>

<Md-tab> is rendered with a button in the browser

Comment: @RafaelAlves, sorry I missed this... You need to add the `.native` modifier. See my edit

Comment: This is deprecated now